# Get Value out of object Hash in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following code:

```
def analytics 
    @user_registrations = User.count(:conditions => ["created_at >= ?", 30.days.ago.to_date], group: "date(created_at)")
    @daily_count = []
    30.times do |day|
      @daily_count << [Date.today - day, @user_registrations['#{Date.today - day}']]
    end
  end
```

which when run with: `<%= simple_format @user_registrations.to_yaml %>` produces:

```
--- !omap 
- '2012-08-23': 11
```

I want to get the `11` value out and put that in my daily_count array.

How can I do that?

update:

```
<%= simple_format @user_registrations.to_yaml %>
<%= simple_format @daily_count.to_yaml %>
```

results in the image:

[image: **enter image description here**]

Comment: I'm confused - if you want the number 11 only, why are you combining it with the date?  Or do you want something more than just the number 11?

Comment: If you can show me how to get the number 11 out, I can figure out the rest. essentially, I want @dailycount to look like [[date, count], [date, count]]. The problem is that sometimes there won't be a count for a date, so I can't just loop through the counts. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace:

```
@daily_count << [Date.today - day, @user_registrations['#{Date.today - day}']]
```

with:

```
@daily_count << [Date.today - day, @user_registrations["#{Date.today - day}"] || 0]
```

Single quotes will cause the #{} escape syntax to be treated as a literal, double quotes cause it to be eval'ed.

Comment: I was looking for [[date, count][date,count]] not [[date_count][date_count]]. Also that doesn't quite work as expected. It does populate with 0 for everything, even when I know there is a user registered on that day.

Comment: I've added an update above that might be useful. I think `Date.today - day` is producing the wrong hash key.